# Can't find Dockerfile in Azure Devops Pipelines (example from Microsoft azure)

Tags: azure, docker

I am following the example from the microsoft website:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/build-image?view=azure-devops

But I get the following issue

```
Starting: Build an image
==============================================================================
Task         : Docker
Description  : Build or push Docker images, login or logout, start or stop containers, or run a Docker command
Version      : 2.192.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/azpipes-docker-tsg
==============================================================================
##[error]Unhandled: No Dockerfile matching  /home/vsts/work/1/s/app/Dockerfile  was found
```

Why is it trying to find the file in a '/home/vsts/work/1/s/' directory when the parameter states 'app/Dockerfile'?

Answer (score -1):

The build task is trying to find your `Dockerfile` at the agent build directory under `app/Dockerfile`.
You will need to check make sure your devops pipeline is properly connected to the repo you are referencing, and is structured accordingly.

Comment: what if the dockerfile s in root dir